# Generating random integer in range that doesn't start at zero

Tags: javascript, random

How can I generate numbers between 7 to 10? So far all I've figured out is generating in a range from 0-10:

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*11)
```

Comment: asked soooo many times previously....

Comment: And the difference between 7 (which you want) and 0 (which you can generate) is how much?

Comment: The more comments of S.Lott's that I read, particularly the late-night ones, the more I like him.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Math.floor(7 + Math.random() * 4)` will generate numbers from 7 to 10 inclusive.

Answer (score 67):

```
function getRandom(min, max) {
    return min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
}

for(var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    console.log(getRandom(7, 10));
}
```

Comment: +1 for making it a general purpose function based on min, max.

Comment: multiplying random by (max-min) doesn't give you the range you want. Min needs to be a sort of "b" in the metaphorical mx+b here.

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli, have you tried it? 43 satisfied customers so far, and I just checked the distribution range on it and it looks right to me. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UCX9c/1/

Comment: oh hey, I didn't see the min at the beginning of that. lol. I thought you were just doing random() * max-min

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Interesting to think of a random number within a range as the slope of a line. I tend to think of it as a set instead. Cool mental trick though. I'm sure a math person would laugh at me.

Answer (score 4):

Just say this:

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*4) + 7
```

This will generate a random number from 0-3 and then add 7 to it, to get 7-10.

Answer (score 0):

```
7 + Math.floor(Math.random()*4)
```